# How to connect to network using TTLS EAP in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, ttls

In Belgium we have FON-public shared networks. They have a web page for the [Belgian FON-network](https://corp.fon.com/en) and FON is only supported by 1 ISP in Belgium. More details [on this page](https://corp.fon.com/en/microsite/proximus).

When you connect to one of these the first webpage you load, will show you a general FON-login page. Once you’ve inputted your username and password—provided by your Internet provider if you share some bandwith on your own router to be shared with other FON-users—you’ll be able to surf normally.

They currently show up as two networks: a “normal” FON-network like there always was before
And quite recently also a AUTOFON-network (apparently a network that skips the step above of inputting username and password, you can input those into your own wireless network settings and your pc should autoconnect to FON from then on)

AUTOFON uses TTLS as EAN and I think that’s where Windows XP can’t follow (that’s what I understood from what I could find on the net) My ISP support couldn’t help me further than saying the AUTOFON network would only work with Windows 8 or Mac .

My question is, is there any possibility of using TTLS on Windows XP (so not for setting up a network but connecting to one)?

Comment: I'd first go to an OS that is more current, and supported...like at least Win 7.  XP is unsupported thus you get no security updates so using TTLS might be just a mute point if there are security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Many networks support both TTLS and PEAP (being very similar), so you could try the latter.

SecureW2 EAP Suite is a [TTLS+PAP client](http://www.eduroam.ie/userdocs/winxp-securew2-ttls.php) for Windows XP, though you'll need to find an older freeware version (it's a commercial product now).

For example, the Windows XP version of the [*eduroam* configuration tool](https://cat.eduroam.org/) comes with some version of SecureW2, which you could extract using 7zip.